Jacobian and Gradient map multiplication vs dot product confusion in model
Hi I have a very simple model and I'm trying to learn the math of it.
Basically, I have an input matrix X (m x n). An output matrix Y (m x n) is formed from some convolution H. The figure of merit is calculated for Y through the adjoint method (this is for electromagnetics). It produces a Gradient map G of size (m x n) that contains the derivative of the FOM with respect to each element of Y.
Now, I have the derivative of each element of Y with respect to G. This is a Jacobian J of size m x n x m x n I believe.
What I want to know is how to obtain the derivative of FOM with respect to X with these two things, the Jacobian J and the gradient matrix G. This will give me the derivative of the FOM with respect to every element in X.
My question is: Is this J x G or J dot G?
Just to let you know, the reason for this is because I have the gradient map, and I have the Jacobian, but this is not part of a model that I can simply use backprop.
Thanks

Welcome to MSE!  As you are a new contributor to the site. I suggest you read some basic information about writing mathematics at this site, see, e.g. How can I format mathematics, There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it, and MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference
